# Como identificar que um Job está sendo executado?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Olá.. Criei um Job no ORACLE, onde ele executa uma PROCEDURE, mas eu queria realizar um SELECT, onde me retornasse o status desse Job.
Pois utilizarei essa informação, para retornar uma resposta ao usuário de que a solicitação que ele havia feito anteriormente está sendo executada, e que ele aguarde.

```
       select 
            job_name as nomeJob, 
            status as status 
        from 
            dba_scheduler_job_run_details
        where 
            job_name = 'JOB_QUE_EU_FIZ'
```

E não retorna o que eu queria.
Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Opa, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow... Dê uma lida nessa documentação que deve te ajudar: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25494_01/scheduse008.htm

Comment: 1 o que eu costumo fazer é a rotina enviar um log de execução por email para o usuário , plsql para envio de email disponiveis a rodo na web    2 a view DBA_JOBS_RUNNING lista os jobs em execução 3 a view DBA_JOBS temmum resumo da última e próxina execução    https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25494_01/scheduse008.htm

Comment: Obrigado, nesse link consegui achar a tabela correta para verificação da execução do Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver, conforme me foi ajudado nos comentários, agora estou realizando a consulta em outra tabela, para conseguir o retorno da execução do Job.

no caso, essa tabela me retorna os jobs ativos, daí então apenas procuro pelo nome do job que criei.

Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando, caso possa ajudar mais alguém:

```
        select 
            job_name  
        from 
            user_scheduler_running_jobs 
        where 
            job_name = 'JOB_QUE_EU_FIZ';
```